# php script output with empty space

Tags: php, bash, scripting

I'm running a script and the output has an empty space first then the print statement follows in bash.How can i remove the empty space.
Please see me script below:

```
!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$file = '/X/X.txt';
$searchfor = '0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored';
// get the file contents, assuming the file to be readable (and exist)
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
// escape special characters in the query
$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
// finalise the regular expression, matching the whole line
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";
// search, and store all matching occurences in $matches
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
    print("OK: No Input Errors Found");
    exit(0);
}
else{
   print ("Warning");
    exit(1);
}
?>
```

The output will be as below ,with the empty space:

## ./script

Warning#bash

Comment: Just a comment, the start of the file has to be like this: `#!/usr/bin/php`

Comment: my apologies that i was a typo error on my end.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add trim() around the string, which should remove spaces at beginning and end of the string.

Comment: i have added trim(), and the white space is still there.

Comment: What operating system are you running? On my debian system there is no extra whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to figure it out, i had to remove the space below:

!/usr/bin/php
empty space

The below worked for me, thank you everyone.
!/usr/bin/php